# update `last_active` on every request

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making a single session application as in only one session is allowed for each user account at some specific time. In the process, I think I need to update the database EVERYTIME the user send a request to the server to update the `last_active` value. This value would later be used when another user tries to login with the same account somewhere else. If the `last_active` is still too close, I will not allow the login. But if the previous logged in user is inactive (as in not sending request to the server) after a 15 or so minutes, I will let the new logged in user in and kick the previous one.

I was just wondering, if this method would put too many load on the server or not.

Comment: Well, requests to your server are unavoidable. IMO what you could eliminate is the database operation, and use something like memcached for this purpose.

Comment: It shouldn't put too much load on your server, but that is a guess. We have no idea how much traffic you get, how you've written your code, how your DB is structured, nor what server instance you are using.

Comment: Since it's a system for small group, it should have less than 100 users I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a root access, you can store the last active, unique session id , and other stuff on memory related storage like redis,APC,memcached.

If you using codeigniter, take a look at [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/caching.html)

me personally, using php fastcache library, you can also see the usage in [this site](https://www.phpfastcache.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your server how soon your server process a request if it can not able to handle frequent request this result your server might be stop for sometime.

Solution:
Better use cache tool like "Redis".